# Change an Observable Collection (bound to JavaFX node) in thread

Tags: multithreading, collections, binding, javafx, observable

What is the correct way to manipulate an Observable collection in a thread, where the collection is already bound to a JavaFX UI-node?

In my sample application, the connection between the collection and the nodes are broken before the thread can do any manipulation; and then they are re-connected after the thread is done. The methods are `disconnectObservable()` and `connectObservable()` respectively. Without these two methods, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread` is reported.

Ideally I would like ChangeObservableTask to make its changes to `mWords`, and then I would call some method to tell `mObservable` to refresh itself and notify its listeners. Is there such a thing?

Thanks.

```
package theapp;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ThreadObList extends Application {
    private final List<String> mWords;
    private final ObservableList<String> mObservable;
    private ListView mListView;
    private Label mCount;

    public ThreadObList() {
        mWords = new LinkedList<>();
        mObservable = FXCollections.observableList(mWords);
        mWords.add("park");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Start thread");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ChangeObservableTask task = new ChangeObservableTask();
                Thread thd = new Thread(task);
                disconnectObservable();
                thd.start();
                try {
                    task.get();
                    System.out.println("ChangeObservableTask exited normally.");
                } 

                catch(Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
                connectObservable();
            }
        });

        mCount = new Label();
        mListView = new ListView();
        VBox root = new VBox(5, btn, mCount, mListView);
        VBox.setVgrow(mListView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        connectObservable();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void connectObservable() {
        mListView.setItems(mObservable);
        mCount.textProperty().bind(Bindings.size(mObservable).asString());
    }

    private void disconnectObservable() {
        mListView.setItems(null);
        mCount.textProperty().unbind();
    }

    private class ChangeObservableTask extends Task<Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            mObservable.add("dart");
            mObservable.add("truck");
            mObservable.add("ocean");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the list is used as the contents of the ListView, you can only manipulate it from the FX Application Thread. See the [`Task` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) for a bunch of usage examples.

You can create a copy of your `ObservableList` and pass it to your task, manipulate the copy and return the results. Then update the `ObservableList` with the results in the `onSucceeded` handler.

Also note that you shouldn't make any blocking calls, such as `task.get()` on the FX Application Thread, as you can make the UI unresponsive by doing so.

So you should do something along the lines of:

```
   btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            ChangeObservableTask task = new ChangeObservableTask(new ArrayList<>(mObservable));
            Thread thd = new Thread(task);
            task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                    mObservable.setAll(task.getValue());
                }
            });
            thd.start();

        }
    });
```

and

```
private class ChangeObservableTask extends Task<List<String>> {
    private final List<String> data ;

    ChangeObservableTask(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> call() throws Exception {
        data.add("dart");
        data.add("truck");
        data.add("ocean");
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll go with your solution. Copying the collection may become a problem if it is very large. I can only hope it will never happen.

Comment: There are other options: e.g. if you are only adding things, just create and return the new list in the call method, and do `addAll` in `onSucceeded`...